# Process second ajax request after first ajax request live search profile view click funciton

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, search

Hello everyone thank you for looking at my problem:)) so i have a google drive link where you can download my project because last time i asked a question it was hard for people to help because they cant access my database. The reason being is that i am hosting it locally and dont have the means to do it any other way. In the zip file is a .csv that you can upload to your phpmyadmin. if you upload it to a database called "names" in a table called "contact_info" with the following column names:

"First", "Last", "Mail", "Phone", "State", "Specialty", "Src", and "Description"

it should all work.

I have a livesearch that works well, once you click on a tr element(contact info), it pops open a div that is supposed to contain contact info, a description, and a picture

Basically i am stuck on how to display information on the div "#profilediv" using an ajax call

i want the click function on the #resulttbl tr to perform an ajax call that will echo out all the all the data from the column clicked.

basically:

```
<?php
echo "<img src='.$row['Src']'>"

echo "<div> <p>.$row['First']."
echo ".$row['Last'].</p>"
echo "<p>.$row['Mail'].</p>"
echo "<p>.$row['Phone'].</p>"
echo "<p>.$row['State'].</p>"
echo "<p>.$row['Specialty'].</p></div>"

echo "<div>.$row['Description'].</div>"
?>
```

but specific to the the tr element clicked....im really stuck on this one and i am not even sure what a function like this is called or really any clue what to google.

sorry if i made this super convoluted. i am really, really new to php and i am trying to grasp how it works /.\

thank you again for the help!!!!:))

Comment: Where is #profilediv, #resulttbl tr and the ajax function?

Comment: Still confusing whether you know how to make the tr click send what you need in ajax or where you are specifically having initial problem. As for all the database population information nobody is going to go to all that trouble so need need to post it as it's not really relevant yet. Same with all the google drive files. Almost nobody will go look at them

Comment: @charliefl honestly i am unsure how to make the click function send the information needed, that is my main issue at the moment. i need it to pick up all the info in the database associated with the tr clicked

Comment: @FelippeDuarte those are located in my php files inside the google drive...although it needs setup as explained on the main post. pls see my comment with charliefl...as i am unsure how to go about writing the ajax call